# How to check and remove if a string variable is in a Dictionary<string, string>?

Tags: c#

*(Hello I'm a newbie so I have no idea how to do this or even if it was already asked before. And also sorry for my English)*

Context: I develop a c# program on the console where the user will write a x,y positions and the algorithm have to count if the user walk through coins (after different movement indications that will influence x and y).

Therefore I created x and y int variables that when put together is a string variable. (Example : "0,2").
**Now I need to check if this x,y position is in one of the values in my Dictionary<string, string > and if true, it have to be removed from this Dictionary.** (Example of my Dictionary : "coin1", "1,2")

How do I do that ?
(Is it clear or do I need to explain more ?)

Here's what I tried but with no sucess :

```
string coord = x + "," + y;

if (CoinPos.Any(kvp=>kvp.Value.Contains(coord)) == true)
{   
      var result = CoinPos.Where(p => p.Value.Contains(location)).Select(p => p.Key);
                    
       CoinPos.Remove(p.key);
       coinCollected++;
}
```

Comment: what is the key and what is the value in the dictionary? Also Why did you put the x and y into a string?

Comment: please show the code that put things into the dictionary

Comment: @pm100 I slightly edited it. Does it answer your first question ? And for the second, I needed to put x and y into a string to be able to compare it with the dictionary string value. (For example the value would be "0,2"). So I put together x and y with a "," between them.

Comment: If you are not going to use the key then Dictionary is not the appropriate data structure. You might simply want a list of points.

Comment: OK so the entries are ("coin1", "0.2"), ("coin2",2.4") etc. What do you mean by 'if the string is in the dictionary'? Do you mean 'coin1' or do you mean '0.2'?

Comment: I agree with @Crowcoder it should probably be a list of points, maybe a tuple of 2 ints

Comment: @pm100 I mean '0,2' even if it's numbers it's a string

Comment: @Crowcoder and Attersson Indeed, I will try this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating the coordinates to a string may not be the best solution because you need to serialize everytime to search, insert, etc and lose some primitive functionality. Maybe you just need a list of tuples of 2 ints to represent the points. But to answer your question:

If this coord can be in more than one item of the dictionary, then

```
foreach(var item in CoinPos.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == coord).ToList())
{
    CoinPos.Remove(item.Key);
}
```

Or if there is at best 1 item that can have this value, then

```
var item = CoinPos.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value == coord);

if (item != null) {
    CoinPos.Remove(item.Key);
}
```

Comment: In the second code block, you should probably use `FirstOrDefault()` (or perhaps `SingleOrDefault()`) and do a null check before calling `Remove()`.

Comment: Point taken, edited.

Comment: Thank you it helped me understand even if my code still doesn't work and put : System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. (it's probably because of another mistake but I put it here in case)

Comment: Why not just use the first code block for both cases?

Answer (score 0):

It would be beneficial in this situation to have the point represent the key, and the value be the coin name:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string point = x + "," + y;
dict.Add(point,"coin1");
if (dict.ContainsKey(point))
{
    dict.Remove(point);
}
```

Also, for scalability sake, you should create a class called coin, that has some variables like position, and score to obtain. This way you can create and keep track of coins easier. If you did this, you could simply create a list of coin objects and iterate of them checking for their position versus player position. Then you could use the methods "ContainsKey", and "Remove"

Comment: @Nobody good to hear, you should mark one of these as an answer if the problem is resolved.

Comment: @pm100 I understand, but I was trying to point out the fact that when using dictionaries, generally you want the key to be the element that you use to search the dictionary. I didn't say that my answer should be marked as correct, I was just saying any one of the answers. I assumed it was resolved because he commented helpful and clear, or something similar on all the answers.

Comment: @acornTime you are quite right

Answer (score -1):

OK

```
string key;
foreach(var kv in CoinPos){
    if(kv.Value == coords){
       key = kv.Key;
       break;
    }
}
if(key.Length > 0)
   CoinPos.Remove(key);
```

Note.

I would store the co-ordiantes in a Point struct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=net-6.0

Comment: Thank you for the idea of the Point struct